# How to search for files greater than a specific size and execute something on them?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to search for files in my different drives that have a size lower than 800Ko and to launch an MD5 checksum of them (with Microsoft tool FCIV).

I think it can be done using the dir command but I am not sure to know how can I check for the filesize (lower than 800Ko) and then being able to retrieve the full path of each file and add it as an argument to the FCIV command.

EDIT: I use this code but actually the proces never ends because it is stucks on directory where I have "access denied".
It is possible to skip those directories ?

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /A HS /s /b c:\') do (
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir c:\ /s /b /A-d') do (
if /I %%~Za LEQ 600000 (
echo %%~Za
fciv -md5 "%%~a" -xml DatabaseMD5.xml  
                            )
                                                                )

@pause
```

Thank you

Comment: on whole drives? this could be really slow..

Comment: Actually, I am already calling the dir /s /b on the whole drive and it is not so slow (less than a minute). The best solution for me should be to generate a single DIR.TXT file and work with it for the script; but I dont find a way with the DIR command to have the "full path" AND the size of a file displayed at once. (because another module of my script is to search for specific files).

Comment: FYI: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d c:') do ( ...`. Note no spaces in `"delims="`. Note  `dir /s /b /a-d c:` will start from current directory on the `c:` drive; use `dir /s /b /a-d c:\ ` to cover the whole drive...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you want to do this to every file on the drive? Anyhow, here's a few tweaks to what you have so far.

```
@echo off
rem   setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R c:\ %%a in (*) do (
    if %%~za GTR 0 if %%~za LSS 800000 (
        echo "%%a" %%~za
        fciv -md5 "%%a" -xml DatabaseMD5.xml 
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: Absolutely no need in the part of the bat file we have been shown, I'm assuming there might be some more processing to go on given it was there in the question.

Comment: Thank you guys. FInally I use this code  (see my edited post) but I have a problem when the DIR is done on a directory where I dont have enough rights. The process stucks on this process and never ends).

Comment: @Isabelle your code will be picking up all files on the drive, including hidden and system files and I suspect it is one of these causing you grief. If you change to my code above, it should only calculate for normal files.